# Unable to connect using cx_Oracle in a Jupyter notebook on VSCode

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, visual-studio-code

I keep getting the following error when I try to execute the cell in a Jupyter notebook on VSCode

`con = cx_Oracle.connect("/@DB")`

`DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". See https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#linux for help`

But the same works fine when I run it in Jupyter Lab.

Answer (score 1):

[**Update**: instead of installing and configuring Instant Client, try the latest version of cx_Oracle, now called [python-oracledb](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a) since this doesn't need Oracle Instant Client. You won't get the DPI-1047 error. Installation is a simple `pip` install.  See the [installation instructions](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html).
Some best-practice notebooks on [GitHub](https://github.com/cjbj/python-oracledb-notebooks) are also available.]

If you are using Oracle Instant Client, and it is the only Oracle software on the computer, then use the `ldconfig` command to set the library search path.  This is always less error prone than trying to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.  See the [Instant Client installation instructions](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html#ic_x64_inst).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes stuff just doesn't work in some IDEs, i am not sure what your question is, i suggest using anaconda (and maybe spyder specifically) it has worked for me with everything so far, but i don't know about cx_Oracle.